# Getting captured image in onActivityResult method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, camera, android-camera

i have small doubt in the below code

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==0 && resultCode==RESULT_OK ){

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        //get the cropped bitmap
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");


        ImageView image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(thePic);

    }
}
```

In the extras.getParcelable("data");  line of the code  here "data" is passed as a key to the parcelable object.

My Question is, is there a key already with the name 'data' defined in the class? or any reason of how this is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It's the camera app's responsibility to add a thumbnail to the `Intent` you receive in `onActivityResult(...)`. It basically adds a `Bitmap` value to the intent with `"data"` as key. Hence it's okay to try and get that value by key from the returned intent. This is also demonstrated in the [Taking Photos Simply tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) on the Android developers website:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

However, from experience I can tell not all camera apps honour this behaviour. I wouldn't rely on the data key to actually be there, or the returned intent nog being `null` for that matter.