# Couldn't upload a picture using google photos

Tags: android, crop, google-photos

I used this piece of code to get the image from the gallery and then crop the image before saving it. Its running up and nicely for android built in gallery but giving NullPointerException in onActivityResult method where we get extras.getParcelable("data") on using google photos app on android. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :D

```
//This is called in oncreate() on clicking the upload from gallery button.
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK ,    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,PICK_FROM_FILE);

//This is called on onActivityResult() method
if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE && data != null) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    //get the cropped bitmap from extras
    Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
    //do whatever with thePic
}
```

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872250/getting-captured-image-in-onactivityresult-method)

Comment: @JohnJoe thanks for sharing the link, but can you please give me solution to the problem, in this i have to first select the image and then crop it before saving it.

Comment: selected image can display on imageView?

Comment: @JohnJoe , if i select it from the android gallery app then the imageview is set, but if i select the photos app, then its giving NullPointerException on extras.getParcelable("data").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me.

```
//This is my onActivityResult method.
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    final Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
    File createDir = new File(root + "AppName" + File.separator);
    if (!createDir.exists()) {
        createDir.mkdirs();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyhhmmss");
    String format = s.format(new Date());
    File file = new File(root + "AppName" + File.separator + format);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            copyFile(new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage)), file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String filePath = file.GetAbsolutePath();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bos);
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}
```

And this is the copyFile method that i have used in this.

```
private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you as well :D